# Ubuntu 19.10: two mpd instances running

Tags: 19.10, mpd

After an upgrade to Ubuntu 19.10 last month, I see I have two instances of [mpd](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/mpd.1.html) (version: 0.21.13) running.

One is 'mpd' and the other is 'mpd --no-daemon'. The first one is what works and the second one can be stopped with no ill effect, but it keeps getting loading at startup anyway.

Can someone offer some advice on fixing this admittedly small issue?

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu provides a system level auto-start file in /etc/xdg/autostart. This is the source of the duplicate process without the --no-daemon flag.

This becomes annoying as it starts mpd even if you disable all the services and when you reboot with a song playing in the background there will be duplicate mpd playing the same song.

To stop mpd from auto starting you can create a corresponding auto start desktop file.

First copy the file provided by ubuntu to your home directory

```
cp /etc/xdg/autostart/mpd.desktop ~/.config/autostart/mpd.desktop
```

Then open this newly copied file in a text editor

```
nano ~/.config/autostart/mpd.desktop
```

And then change the following line to false:

```
Hidden=true
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=false
```

The first line will disable it for all desktop and the second is specific to gnome. Changing the first is probably enough, but I have changed both in my file.

Now on next reboot you will only have one mpd instance.